# my `couchdb External Processes` return error

Tags: couchdb, ubuntu-10.10

i'm using couchdb 1.0.2 and i'v following [this tutorial](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/ExternalProcesses) to make an External Process...
nothing different with the tutorial... (even for the code and folder structure)...

the error message is

```
{"error":"{bad_return_value,{os_process_error,{exit_status,2}}}","reason":"{gen_server,call,\n            [<0.1116.0>,\n             {execute,{[{<<\"info\">>,\n
```

while googling, i got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739313/can-get-couchdb-external-http-handlers-to-work), but the error is different, and the answer not fix my problem...
i'm using ubuntu 10.10, and couchdb 1.0.2.. is this that caused the error??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the problem..... in the [tutorial](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/ExternalProcesses), it says to run an external process I must configure my `local.ini` like this:

```
[external]
```

There are two ways you can fix it:

1) add `python` at the config `local.ini`

```
[external]  
test = python /usr/local/src/couchdb/test.py
```

2) add `#!/usr/bin/python2.6` (I use Python 2.6) at the top of test.py

Comment: Did you put `#!/usr/bin/python` [or whatever the appropriate path for your system] at the top of test.py?

Comment: @Matt... ya,.. i have try it... and it works too... but from the tutor page (wiki.apache.org) there is no `#!/usr/bin/python` at the top of test.py... so i decide to add `python /usr ...` in my config.. it because i try it first than the second one...